# Transpose column and group dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to change a dataframe in R to group multiple rows by a measurement. The table has a location (`km`), a size (`mm`) a `count` of things in that size bin, a `site` and `year`. I want to take the sizes, make a column from each one (2, 4 and 6 in this example), and place the corresponding count into each the row for that location, site and year.

It seems like a combination of transposing and grouping, but I can't figure out a way to accomplish this in R. I've looked at `t()`, `dcast()` and `aggregate()`, but those  aren't really close at all.

So I would go  from something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(km=c(rep(32,3),rep(50,3)), mm=rep(c(2,4,6),2), count=sample(1:25,6), site=rep("A", 6), year=rep(2013, 6))

  km mm count site year
1 32  2    18    A 2013
2 32  4     2    A 2013
3 32  6    12    A 2013
4 50  2     3    A 2013
5 50  4    17    A 2013
6 50  6    21    A 2013
```

To this:

```
  km  site  year  mm_2  mm_4  mm_6
1 32    A   2013   18     2    12
2 50    A   2013    3    17    21
```

Edit: I tried the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584) in a suggested duplicate, but I did not work for me, not really sure why. The answer below worked better.

Comment: `tidyr::spread(df, mm, count)`

Comment: Use the `sep` argument in `tidyr::spread(df, mm, count, sep = "_")`

Comment: Use `set.seed()` to make `sample()` reproducible in the code to generate your example data frame.

Comment: @www maybe let Markus post that solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comment above, we can use the `sep` argument in `spread`:

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df, mm, count, sep = "_")
  km site year mm_2 mm_4 mm_6
1 32    A 2013    4   20    1
2 50    A 2013   15   14   22
```

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned `dcast()`, here is a method using it.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(km=c(rep(32,3),rep(50,3)), 
                 mm=rep(c(2,4,6),2),
                 count=sample(1:25,6),
                 site=rep("A", 6),
                 year=rep(2013, 6))

library(reshape2)
dcast(df, ... ~ mm, value.var="count")

#   km site year  2  4  6
# 1 32    A 2013 13 10 20
# 2 50    A 2013  3 17  1
```

And if you want a bit of a challenge you can try the base function `reshape()`.

```
df2 <- reshape(df, v.names="count", idvar="km", timevar="mm", ids="mm",  direction="wide")
colnames(df2) <- sub("count.", "mm_", colnames(df2))
df2

#   km site year mm_2 mm_4 mm_6
# 1 32    A 2013   13   10   20
# 4 50    A 2013    3   17    1
```